# Possible bug with MarkDown rendering involving <code> tag

Tags: support, markdown-rendering

The [following revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/18570556/1) has a weird rendering. The mono-space text formatting is spilled out of the code area.

> [image]

Looking at the MarkDown source, it seems to be caused by a mix of `<code>` tag and 4 spaces indent:

```
<code>

        -G grplist
              Select by real group ID (RGID) or name.  This selects the processes whose real group name or ID is in the grplist list.  The real group ID identifies the group of the user who created the process, see getgid(2).

       -g grplist
              Select by session OR by effective group name.  Selection by session is specified by many standards, but selection by effective group is the logical behavior that several other operating systems use.  This ps will select by session when the list is
              completely numeric (as sessionsare).  Group ID numbers will work only when some group names are also specified.  See the -s and --group options.

       --Group grplist
              Select by real group ID (RGID) or name.  Identical to -G.

       --group grplist
              Select by effective group ID (EGID) or name.  This selects the processes whose effective group name or ID is in grouplist.  The effective group ID describes the group whose file access permissions are used by the process (see getegid(2)).  The -g
              option is often an alternative to --group.</code>
So you could get the group ID for your program using <code>getpgrp [pid-of-your-program] </code> then call <code>ps -G [group-if-of-your-program]</code>.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's an opening `<code>` tag. Then there's an indented block, i.e. a code block. This codeblock happens to include a closing `</code>` tag, but (as it *should*, since it is within a codeblock) it's considered part of the code block, and not an actual HTML tag.

And thus the opening `<code>` tag at the top is never closed; the tags are unbalanced. So this revision is broken, and there shouldn't be any expectation how that ends up being renderered. In particular I don't consider "broken output for broken input" a bug.

[Your edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/18570556/revisions) shows that it was unnecessary to hand-craft HTML for this post in the first place; in addition, even for the broken first revision the client-side preview shows the exact same thing as the server-rendered version, so the problem was immediately visible. Both of these things were ignored by the OP.